# Jquery code is not working inside AngularJs functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am right now working on a project which has lot of jquery code and i am migrating that to angular, but it needs to deliver as soon as possible(lack of time to change each piece of code).

Code looks like....

```
var app = angular.module('audiapp', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('audiLayoutCtrl', function ($scope, dataFactory) {

    $scope.editbutton = function () {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var editable = $(this).parents('.editable');
        editable.find('.editable-body').hide();
        editable.find('.editable-form').show();
        editable.find('.editable-toggle').hide();
    };

}
```

here in this piece of code the editbutton function is getting called but jquery code inside is not working.

I am sorry if i am completly un reasonable as i am very new to angular js.

Comment: how is `editbutton` called... you have to pass the even object to `editbutton` using `editbutton($event)` from your event handler like `ng-click="editbutton($event)"`

Comment: Also the controller is not the right place to do dom manipulations, you can use a directive for that

Comment: I will try with directives. thanks. still not sure how i am gonna do it... Thanks Arun

Comment: @SamirShah `this` in `editbutton` method refers to $scope, not the element that is being clicked.

Comment: The answer I provided doesn't require a function.

Comment: use Jquery.noconflict() see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496834/jquery-and-angularjs-not-working-together

Answer (score 3):

I think you should change

```
var editable = $(this).parents('.editable');
```

to

```
var editable = jQuery(this).parents('.editable');
```

`$` maybe conflict between Angular and Jquery

Comment: I got this warning message
"event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead"

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery inside the controller is considered as bad practice in Angular JS. The hide and show of particular element is very simple in angular js. You can try like this

HTML

```
<div class="editable">
    <div class="editable-body" ng-hide="editing"></div>
    <a class="editable-toggle" ng-click="editButton()" ng-hide="editing"></a>

    <form class="editable-form" ng-show="editing"></form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('audiapp', ['ngResource']);
app.controller('audiLayoutCtrl', function ($scope, dataFactory, $element) {

  $scope.editing = false;
  $scope.editbutton = function () {
    $scope.editing = true;
  };

}
```

Comment: Yes I know Fizer but there are like 3000+ lines of Jquery Code. I dont have that much time to migrate like this to Angular. Thanks Mate.

Comment: I feel the same lot of time to write jquery code inside the controller.Always i feel bad, tried to write everything in directive. But I can understand you. If you want Jquery element, use `angular.element('.editable')`. It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but here's another option. Like @derekshull mentioned, you can do this without jQuery. Here's a similar solution utilizing the `ng-disabled` directive. The form is disabled when you're not editing it, but is still visible if you need it to be.

```
ng-disabled="!editing"
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saylesc/e92adx20/11/)

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `editbutton` function refers to `$scope` not the DOM element being clicked. You need a directive so you can easily refer to the element being clicked inside the directive constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing **$('.this').parents('.editable');**  to **$('.editable parent').parents('.editable');**. may be **$('this')** will not point to the exact object inside angular js

```
var app = angular.module('audiapp', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('audiLayoutCtrl', function ($scope, dataFactory) {

    $scope.editbutton = function () {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var editable = $('.editable parent').parents('.editable');
        editable.find('.editable-body').hide();
        editable.find('.editable-form').show();
        editable.find('.editable-toggle').hide();
    };

}
```

**Note :**

I have not tried it . Just a sugesstion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need an Angular function to handle this.  Just use ng-click and ng-show/ng-hide:

```
<div class="editable">
    <div class="editable-body" ng-hide="editing"></div>
    <a class="editable-toggle" ng-click="editing=true" ng-hide="editing"></a>
    <form class="editable-form" ng-show="editing"></form>
</div>
```

So if you click the anchor it sets editing to true, which will hide .editable-body and .editable-toggle...then it will show .editable-form.