# AngularJS text suggestion textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on text suggestion textbox using angularjs.

Below is my page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="BaseCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="BaseController">
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" ng-model="fnamequery" ng-change="toggleSuggest()">
        <p ng-repeat="fname in fnames | filter:fnamequery">{{fname}}</p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my controller file BaseCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('TextApp',[]).controller('BaseController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.fnames =  ["Aida", "Aidan", "Alla", "Allen", "Beverly", "Bea", "Caleb", "Catherine"];
$scope.toggleSuggest = function () {
    console.log($scope.fnamequery);
    if ($scope.fnamequery == '') $('p').hide();
    else $('p').show();
}
});
```

In the future I am planning to pull up the names from the database via Web API call, but for now I am just trying to get it to work with hard-coded values.

Now I get all the values shown on the page. The values do get filtered out as I type something in but initially everything gets displayed

Comment: Can you make a working JSFiddle for this ? :)

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-ap"> should be
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="name">
?

Comment: @Mahakala, I tried adding the name but then I get "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TextApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'TextApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: now it is a totally different question than the one I answered after the last update.

Comment: your new question should be solved by setting your app name `ng-app="TextApp"` in the wrapper HTML tag

Comment: sorry guys, I made updates trying to solve the errors. Now I do not get errors but still do not get the desired result. i would post another question biut it will be considered a duplicate

Comment: can you show how you did solve it ? it would be great if  you add it as an answer rather than updating the question so it can help others with similar issues in the future.

Comment: I did not solve it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$('p').hide()` and `$('p').show()` to hide/show DOM elements which looks more like jQuery methods to me. Your code sample is throwing this error :

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined at Object.MyCtrl.$scope.toggleSuggest

Angular's `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives should do the trick in this case :

```
<body ng-controller="BaseController">
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="text" ng-model="fnamequery">
        <p ng-repeat="fname in fnames | filter:fnamequery" ng-hide="fnamequery==''">{{fname}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
function BaseController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.fnamequery = '';
    $scope.fnames = ["Aida", "Aidan", "Alla", "Allen", "Beverly", "Bea", "Caleb","Catherine"];
}
```

**Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tunecino/pz3u3qur/).**

Comment: Unfortunately did not work for me - no errors but nothing happend as I enter values into the textbox

Comment: did you check the jsFiddle link ? that was not the way you want it to work ? and either while typing in the input there is no errors shown in the console ?

Comment: Yes, fidlle looks good except when you enter one letter, it shows you all options plus an extra option 'false'. But still, somehow the same code does not work on my machine at all. Must be some directives I am missing

Comment: yeah sorry for the `false` :) I added it to your `$scope.fnames` as one more name so I can be sure it is interpreted as a string. no prob & good luck with that

Comment: thanks! one last thing that may save you more future issues or may not, I'm not sure as I never used both frameworks in a single project. I guess you did define jQuery as a global function, so maybe it is caused by the the use of `$` sign as it is the case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011095/jquery-code-is-not-working-inside-angularjs-functions#answer-21011132) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714286/call-jquery-function-from-angularjs-controller#answer-29194049).