# Can't read property length of undefined - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

one of my variable throws undefined that causes an error:

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="search()">
   <div class="input-group col-md-6 typeahead-wrapper">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchkeyword.keystring" class="typeahead">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" id="goSearch" type="submit">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
           </button>
        </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is function inside controller:

```
$scope.search = function() {
        //alert($scope.searchkeyword.keystring);
     $http.get('myurl'+$scope.searchkeyword.keystring).then(sucesscalback,errorcalback);
        function sucesscalback(response)
        {
            //some code
        }
        function errorcalback(failure)
        {
            //some code
        }
```

I am trying to implement typeahead, it was working fine, but as I pasted the below code inside controller (after/before the search function):

```
$scope.substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substrRegex;
            matches = [];
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
            $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    matches.push({ value: str });
                }
            });
            cb(matches);
        };
    };

           $scope.states = ['Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
           var myTypeahead =  $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1,
              },
              {
                name: 'states',
                displayKey: 'value',
                source: $scope.substringMatcher($scope.states)
              });
```

My keystring returns undefined:

> $scope.searchkeyword.keystring

substringMatcher looks the problem to me.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by wrapping substringMatcher inside:

```
$.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
      // My code for substringMatcher
}
```

source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496834/jquery-and-angularjs-not-working-together)