# How should I setup the use of typeahead with Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use **typeahead.js** but all I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I'm:

- Loading it after jQuery
- Not using `$(document).ready(...)` anywhere in my scripts
- Using Angular JS (even I don't think it's an issue)
- Loading jQuery after whole angular stuff
- Made sure all scripts exist and are being loaded.

This is what my whole resources loading looks like (with out typeahead load):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/rules.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/dependencies/checklist-model.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery.js"></script>  THIS NOT ANOTHER jQuery
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

#### Important:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery.js"></script>` is NOT another jQuery, it's just a function which does some selections.

What I've tried for loading (after all those sripts):

- Loading the bundle:

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dependencies/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>`
- Loading both typeahead and bloodhound:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dependencies/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dependencies/bloodhound.min.js"></script>`

- Loading even a [bootstrap3 version of typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead):

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dependencies/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>`

None of these worked, I looked for any [issues on github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues) but didn't find ... [This is what I'm getting](http://imgur.com/O21HtwT), and just in case, I'm using last version of Chrome.

### Update | Found the issue

I found out what's causing it, but I can't fingure out or understand why and how to fix it.

So, `jQuery/jquery.js`, which is NOT another jQuery is the file making it all fail and looks exactly like this:

```
function dojQuery () {

  $(".hover-resize").hover(

    function() { $(this).css("font-size","95px"); },
    function() { $(this).css("font-size","75px"); }
  );

  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
      var location = $(this).attr('href');
      window.location.href = location;
      return false;
  });

  $('#modifyItemModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#myOrderReview").modal('show');
  });

  $('#reviewConfirmationModal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function() {
    $("#orderReview").modal('show');
  });

  $('.supervisorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function() {
    $("#orderReview").modal('show');
  });

};
```

And the function declared is being called one within an Angular controller by simple invoking `dojQuery();` Not including the fie invoking the function makes it all work good for tyepeahead.... Finally I guess it's about the jquery conflict stuff but I can't understand the fix.

Comment: Two jQuery libraries loaded?

Comment: @diegoaguilar I don't think this is a dependency issue. I think it is a no JQuery no conflict issue because you are loading JQuery then AngularJS, then some other version of JQuery. Google JQuery no conflict.

Comment: Unrelated, but as far as I remember, Bootswatch already bundles Bootstrap 3. So remove the `<link>` that points to bootstrap.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer and check my edit, I'm not loading jquery twice.

Comment: Can you open the console and refresh your page. Then post the stack trace here.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer check this http://imgur.com/O21HtwT

Comment: @bassxzero I googled but I can't understand what I should try

Comment: @diegoaguilar I think AngularJS is overwriting some function that JQuery has previously set. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496834/jquery-and-angularjs-not-working-together the bottom solution shows you how to use no conflict.

Comment: @diegoaguilar Also I think in this case the Firefox console would show you a much more descriptive/helpful error message than Chrome does.